# defining an Enum instance in scalaz

Tags: scalaz

How would one do the analogue of the following in scalaz?

```
ghci> data Day = Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday deriving (Eq, Show, Enum)
ghci> [Monday .. Wednesday]
[Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday]
```

For instance I should be able to do `(Monday |-> Wednesday)` and get `List(Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday)` once an Enum instance has been defined.

The Enum instances in [AnyVal.scala](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/AnyVal.scala) seem pretty complicated. Is there a simpler way?